If $G$ is finitely generated and $G/N$ is finitely presented, then $N$ is the normal closure of a finite set

Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated group and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N$ is a finitely presented .Then show that $N$ is a normal closure of some finite set of $G$.

Self studying presentations and free groups, and have been stuck on this problem for quite some time. I already found an answer here: If $G$ is finitely generated and $G/N$ is finitely presented , then $N$ is normal closure of finite set. but the steps taken go a little fast for me. I have a question about the answer given by Andreas Caranti, specifically the part indicated in bold text; the rest I more or less understand, but I wrote it down anyway just to be sure :)
I understand the following result he quotes (also given as a hint in Clara Löh's introduction to geometric group theory Exercise 2.E.16):

if a group is finitely presented with respect to a particular finite set of generators, then it is so with respect to any finite set of generators.

Let $S$ be a finite set of generators of $G$, so $G = \langle S \rangle_G$ and let $F$ be the free group on the letters in $S$. Then we have the following natural surjective morphisms
$$
F \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} G \overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow} G/N,
$$
we consider the composite morphism $\varphi: F \longrightarrow G/N$ and let $K = \ker \varphi$. Then,

By the above result, there is a finite subset $T$ of $F$ such that $K$ is the normal closure in $F$ of $T$.

I believe here we obtain $T$ as follows: as $\varphi$ is surjective, we have that the finite set $\varphi(S)$ generates $G/N$. By the above result, we can use these letters to obtain a finite set of relations $R$ so that $G/N = \langle \varphi(S) \mid R \rangle$. We then obtain $T \subseteq F$ by taking an element in the preimage of each relation in $R$ under $\varphi$.
But why exactly is $K = \langle T \rangle_F^{\lhd}$? I understand the inclusion $\langle T \rangle_F^{\lhd} \subseteq K$ as $\varphi(t)$ is trivial for each $t \in T$ and $K$ is a normal subgroup of $F$. But why does $ K \subseteq \langle T \rangle_F^{\lhd}$? I feel that we could prove this using some universal property, but I'm not that familiar yet with the theory, so any help is appreciated.
The rest of the proof goes as follows:

Now the image of $K$ under $f$ is $N$,

I understand this. We have $f(K) \subseteq N$ because when $f(x)\in f(K)$ for some $x\in K$, by definition $\varphi(x) = f(x)N = N$, which implies $f(x)\in N$. To prove $N \subseteq f(K)$ we consider an arbitrary $n \in N$. By surjectivity of $f$, we have $x\in F$ such that $f(x)=n$ and indeed $x \in K$ as $$\varphi(x) = f(x)N = nN = N.$$

so $N$ is the normal closure in $G$ of the finite set $f(T)$.

Since $N = f(K)$, $K = \langle T \rangle_F^{\lhd}$ and $f$ is surjective, we indeed have $N = \langle f(T) \rangle_G^{\lhd}$ and we are done.
Thanks in advance!

They're both, by definition, the kernel of the composition.

@SteveD Hi, I understand that when we say $G / N = \langle \varphi(S) \mid R \rangle$, this means per definition that there is a canonical isomorphism between $G/N$ and $F' /\langle R \rangle_{F'}^{\lhd}$, where $F'$ is the free group on the set of letters $\varphi(S)$. I suppose that there is a way to relate this to the group $F$ using $\varphi$? Not fully sure how to do this.

Do you want to prove: if a group is finitely presented with respect to a particular finite set of generators, then it is so with respect to any finite set of generators. Because this implies that $\ker \varphi$ is the normal closure of a finite set.

@Functor No, I am okay with that result!  I'm interested in what I've written in my earlier comment.
